# does a meteor.JS app compile to node.JS? If so, how

Tags: node.js, compilation, meteor

I remember hearing from someone that you can simply type in a command to compile a meteor.JS app into a node.JS app, and then deploy it as a node.JS app. Is that correct? Also, does that mean I can build a completely node.JS app by first building it in Meteor, and then using a command to compile it into node? If so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use tool for doing that:
https://github.com/onmodulus/demeteorizer

Tutorial:
http://blog.modulus.io/demeteorizer

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for `meteor bundle` ([See documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteorbundle)). Meteor bundle constructs a tar.gz file from your meteor application. Once extracted, you should be able to run `main.js` in the extraction directory and your application built with meteor will run as a standard node application.

For clarification, here are some steps to bundle and run your node application built with meteor.

Within your meteor application directory, run:

```
meteor bundle appName.tar.gz
```

Then, unpack the bundle that meteor creates:

```
tar -xvzf appName.tar.gz
```

If the proper version of node is installed, you should be able to set your environment variables, and run the application.

```
export MONGO_URL='mongodb://localhost'
export ROOT_URL='http://myApp.com'
export PORT=5000
```

And finally, run your application. In the directory that you extracted the tar.gz file to, run:

```
node main.js
```